# Example of independent observations

Tags: regression, logistic, independence, iid

I came across an interesting (to me, at least) question. I want to **predict the probability that a given boat will win a race**. The dataset is something like:

- Y: winner (0-1)
- X1: size of the sail
- X2: weight of the boat
- X3: length in miles of the race

We collected the data **across several races**. It means that there will be **some observations from the same race**. At first impression, **observations are not independent**, as there can only be one winner per race. **This would warrant against the use of a logistic regression** or, at least, against **relying too much on statistical inference**.

First, is it true that observations are not independent?

Second, does it impact the validity of a logistic regression model?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: A first way to understand what was considered independence or not is to reflect on whether the result of one race will affect the other. I do not think so. So there is independence between the observations, at least I think so. A good suggestion to start your model would be http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/148-logistic-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r/

Comment: If you include the same race more than once then those observations are not independent, since only one can win.  It also raises the issue that the probability of winning depend on features of the opponents too and the numbers in each race